# Removing null namespaces from input xml in nodejs

Tags: node.js, xml

I am paasing some id's of media(eg.movie) in xml format and getting metadata of that media in xml format.For this, first I am receiving xml which has ID's in it then coverting it to json using xml2js mudule and once the metadata parsing is done again I am converting it to xml as the output should be in xml but the problem is there is a null tag with  which causes the parsing error. I looked for if any option is there in the used node module but couldn't find anything.I don't want this namespace to appear along with  tag.

Comment: The null tag is in input xml file xsi:nil="true.

Comment: Found solution for it :-) closing question.